# Java SSL server not accepting intermediate certificate chain

Tags: java, ssl, netty

I have implemented a (Netty 3.6.6, Java 6) server which accepts SSL/TLS connections, and is required to authenticate the client's certificate chain. I have the common CA's in my truststore. Barring the case described here, the server's SSL implementation basically works. Given a valid signed certificate (which works for connecting to other servers), I can successfully connect to my server with:

```
openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1 -key test.key -cert test.pem -CAfile capath.pem
```

If, however, the certificate and intermediates are concatenated together and I connect with:

```
openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1 -key test.key -cert all.pem
```

then I get `unable to find valid certification path to requested target` thrown; I expect this approach to work.

My code is (abbreviated):

```
public class MySslConnectionHandler extends FrameDecoder {
    // this class is added into the netty ChannelPipeline (not shown)

    private SSLContext sslContext;

    public MySslConnectionHandler() {
        KeyStore clientKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance('JKS');
        clientKeyStore.load(new FileInputStream(trustStoreFilename), trustStorePassword);

        PKIXSSLContextFactory contextFactory = new PKIXSSLContextFactory(serverKeyStore, keyStorePassword, clientKeyStore, true);

        this.sslContext = contextFactory.buildSSLContext();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Channel channel, ChannelBuffer buffer) throws Exception {
        SSLEngine engine = sslContext.createSSLEngine();
        engine.setUseClientMode(false);
        engine.setNeedClientAuth(true);
        engine.setEnabledProtocols(new String[] {"TLSv1","SSLv3"});

        SslHandler sslHandler = new SslHandler(engine);
        sslHandler.setEnableRenegotiation(false);

        ChannelFuture handshakeFuture = sslHandler.handshake();
        handshakeFuture.addListener(new MySslHandshakeListener(engine));

        return buffer.readBytes(buffer.readableBytes());
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Our customers are reporting this behaviour differs from other servers they use, so I don't want this to cause them problems; is this reasonable? (Extensive googling hasn't helped...)

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expectation is wrong. `openssl s_client -cert file` uses **only the first cert**, which must be the client cert. Putting additional certs, chain or other, in that file is ignored. As a result `s_client` (via libssl client) sends an incomplete chain. Normally the server can't validate this.

Although `-CAfile` and/or `-CAdir` are documented as providing roots for `s_client` to validate the *peer* (server) cert, libssl *also* uses the truststore to fill out the chain it sends if necessary and possible; apparently you have your chain cert(s) in `cacert.pem` and this happened.

I assume your customers aren't using `s_client` since it has very limited ability to send and receive suitable data.
If you or someone wrote or writes a real application using libssl, you can set a (whole) chain by calling `SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file` instead of `SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file` or you can build the chain from individual certs with `SSL_CTX_add_extra_chain_cert`. (If you have only one intermediate, these are practically equivalent.) Not to mention what you can do in other languages like Java, perl and dotNET. `s_client` is designed as a test and debugging tool and doesn't do these; it only does `use_certificate` which uses only the first cert.

Caveat: this is all for OpenSSL through 1.0.1. 1.0.2 now in beta is announced to have changes in cert and chain validation I haven't examined yet. Although based on past practice I confidently expect the *defaults* will continue to be as in earlier versions.

If you really need a Java server to accept a client sending an incomplete chain (which per RFC it shouldn't need to) you can put the first intermediate not sent (which here is the first intermediate period) in server truststore. But I believe (can't easily test) in this case Java will entirely ignore the rest of the chain so you'll have to monitor manually or by some other means for e.g. revocation.

Comment: Thanks for this. The openssl commands are what a colleague used to test the server, and to give the user enough of a clue for them to fix their (unknown) implementation. I realise now that these _might_ be distinct problems. Without the user's implementation I can't be sure that I can reproduce their exact problem; given that they are connecting fine to other servers, either we have a bug somewhere, or the other servers are somehow less stringent. Tricky! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why do you believe Java will ignore the rest of the chain? It must establish a path from the actual client certificate via the chain to a certificate in the truststore. How does that constitute ignoring?

Comment: @EJP if the actual chain is SheepMolly / Shepherd1 / WoollyRoot and you put Shepherd1 in the truststore (because the noncompliant peer only sends SheepMolly), then it appears Java will build the chain SheepMolly - Shepherd1 and stop there because Shepherd1 is trusted, at least according to `HandshakeCompletedEvent.getPeerCertificates`. But in reality Shepherd1 may have been revoked, and a relier that looked at the full chain would have detected that.

Comment: @Liche if you can't see into the client, can you capture their connection on your server or at least your server's network segment with Wireshark or equivalent? That will make it easy to figure out exactly what they're sending; if it *should* work then you have something definite to fix, if not you can tell them what to fix. Getting permission to capture on a production sensitive network sometimes is an issue; if you can have this client connect instead to a test server you set up that is often easier. ...

Comment: ... Alternatively, but possibly even worse from the getting-permission factor, you can switch on quite detailed logging in JSSE with sysprop `javax.net.debug`. But then you have to trek through a LOT of junk to find the good parts, you can't just point and click like Wireshark.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Wireshark is a nice idea, but as you rightly point out getting access to that part of the network is going to involve paperwork... I've asked support to get more information from the client, which hopefully will be an easier way to figure out exactly what they are doing. Thanks!